# Strange issue using jQuery to grab an element

Tags: jquery

I have a page that is using Ajax to refresh some data on a table at regular intervals.  I wanted to somehow "capture" certain variables in a particular column on that table BEFORE the data is replaced/updated.... and then loop through those "old values", comparing them with the "new values".   And then, for any "new" values/rows that have come in to us from Ajax/JSON, I want to add a class ("new_row") to those rows... for a "highlight-then-fade" effect once they are drawn.

Well, what I'm doing is, in the routine that parses out the new incoming JSON data, I thought I'd simply use the following to "grab" the "old" table:

```
var mytable = $('#cities_table");
```

But trying to loop through this with an .each (looking at tr's) was giving me strange errors, so I thought I'd dump out that mytable object.

And when I do, I see:

```
({0:{}, length:1, context:{location:({}), search_incidents:{0:{}, 1:{}, 2:{}, 3:{}, 4:{}, 5:{}, 6:{}, 7:{}, 8:{}}, ZeroClipboardMovie_2:{}, ZeroClipboardMovie_3:{}, _html5shiv:1}, selector:"#cities_table"})
```

Now, "search_incidents" is in another form on the page... and the ZeroClipboardMovies are also elsewhere on the page.

I don't get why I'm not able to "grab" that table ??

Comment: Are you possibly bringing in new elements with the same IDs as already existing ones? I could see that causing problems...

Comment: Well, I'd thought of that, so I moved my "var mytable" line to being the first line in the JSON callback routine, so that it is BEFORE the rest of the code where we parse out the JSON object and start forming it into strings of HTML to be "written over" the original table.

Comment: Presumably you have access to the data which populated your old values in the first place. Would it not make more sense to store said values in an array, parse your new JSON values and compare them as plain old Javascript objects instead? It would save you wrangling with the HTML.

Comment: I suppose I could do that.  I had thought this might be easier, so I went with it first.  I even just tried using document.getElementById('clients_table') and Firefox's mytable.toSource(); simply comes back with ({}), as if it's there (not null) but it's empty. <sigh>

Comment: OK, using an array (globally) to store the old values is working fine.  Thanks!